# sumifs in excel where the criteria is a range possible?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

assume a table where one column has values T1...Tn. how would I get the sum of another column where the corresponding T value is a set?

```
=SUMIFS(...,Sheet1!$D$1:$D$250,{"T1","T2","T3","T4","T5"})
```

I tried this but it is only picking values corresponding to T1

Comment: Wrap the SUMIFS in SUM.

Comment: Or wrap in SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: `=SUM((Sheet1!$D$1:$D$250={"T1","T2","T3","T4","T5"})*E1:E250)`